# OpenCV Camera Calibration

Tags: c++, opencv, video, mp4, camera-calibration

i'm using Camera calibration With OpenCV tutorial (http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html). When I use .mp4 video file as input, my program fails and gives this error:
Parsing error (): Valid XML should start with '') in icvXMLParse, file ........\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 2252

Could anyone please tell me what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: which xml ? this needs more detail.

Comment: exact error is: OpenCV Error: Parsing error (VIDEO0013.mp4(1): Valid XML should start with '<?xml ...?>') in icvXMLParse, file ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\core\src\persistence.cpp, line 2252

i really dont know what is wrong. the xml file i read from is ok, it seems, that i shoud use just xml file as input for calibration.

Comment: the sample seems to expect an imagelist in an xml file. if you want to use a video instead , you can't just pass the name of the video to the code that expects xml.

Comment: i understand it the same way, but i saw another guy using this and he just wrote number one as input for camera and code works well with his camera. it seems he doesnt change anything else.

and also the xml comments says, that you just need to write path to the video.. you can see the code here: http://docs.opencv.org/_downloads/in_VID5.xml

Comment: total different story. (yes, videocapture accepts both device numbers as well as filenames)

Comment: sorry, but i still don't get why it's so difference, because it's given in one place what will be your input as you can see here: http://docs.opencv.org/_downloads/in_VID5.xml

Comment: ahh, sorry, seems i'm looking at adifferent sample for this. sorry for the noise again.

Comment: i'm really crazy about this, cause it seems i can use any input i want but it's not so eazy as it seems..

Answer (score 1):

In the example (camera_calibration.cpp), make this change to the readStringList method:

was:

```
static bool readStringList( const string& filename, vector<string>& l )
{
    l.clear();
    FileStorage fs(filename, FileStorage::READ);
    if( !fs.isOpened() )
        return false;
```

should be:

```
static bool readStringList( const string& filename, vector<string>& l )
{
    l.clear();
    FileStorage fs;
    try {
        fs.open(filename, FileStorage::READ);
    }
    catch (...) {
        return false;
    }
    if( !fs.isOpened() )
        return false;
```

Then you can use a video filename instead of an xml input file, and the program won't crash.  The FileStorage constructor and open method throw an exception if the input file isn't xml/yml, and the exception needs to be caught.

Answer (score 0):

Well done. I had the same problem and I fixed following your point applying the try..catch...

C:\OpenCVProjects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Release>ConsoleApplication1.exe -w 9 -
h 6 -s 2 -o camera.yml -op -oe video.mp4

When the live video from camera is used as input, the following hot-keys may be
used:
  , 'q' - quit the program
  'g' - start capturing images
  'u' - switch undistortion on/off
Calibration succeeded. avg reprojection error = 0.49